# ASP .NET Logout when url is modified or refreshed

Tags: asp.net

hi i would like to know how would you lougout an user if he modifies the url or refreshes the web pages like in bank web sites
in asp .net.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: do banks do that? Logging a user out when they press F5 or changes the URL? That's a weird behaviour I've never seen

Comment: yes they do, try in your internet banking

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a solution similar to Vignesh Kumar's answer by using roles and restricting access to pages based on the roles a user has. When a user logs in I check which pages they can access based on their assigned roles and build the navigation menu accordingly so that they're not able to navigate to restricted pages.

In my master page's Page_Load method I check whether a user has access to the page they're trying to access and if not I log them out and redirect them to the login screen.